# Временная блокировка или отключение USB порта Java

Tags: java, jna

Как временно отключить(заблокировать) один USB порт с помощью java? В библиотеках JNA или usb4java не нашел нужных методов, разве что определил девайсы со всеми данными (порт, id и тд). Еще подойдет вариант, если заблокировать устройство подключенное к определенному USB порту. (Windows 7/10)

Comment: Неподходящий вы язык выбрали для этой задачи. Такие вещи обычно решаются с помощью C.

Comment: ТЗ такое, нужно вертеться )

Comment: так а использовав jni/jna вы не на java решаете задачу, а если это просто должно вызываться из управляющего кода на java - вы хоть черта лысого можете запустить через jni/jna